# Javascript GPA Calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong with my gpa calculator?  I'm working on a a webpage that will allow users to enter letter grades for three specific classes.  I've created the html and javascript code that converts letter grades to point values.  I've also created a function that adds the point grades together then divides by four to output a gpa for the three classes.  I've worked on this for several weeks and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I'm sure there are many different ways to do what I'm trying to do.  However, I'm looking for a way to make me code because the way I've written the code makes the most sense to me.  Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="styles.css"> <title>Center for Health Information Technology
</title> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function calculate()
 {
  var x=document.getElementById("result1").value;
  var y=document.getElementById("result2").value;
  var z=document.getElementById("result3").value;
  var a=document.getElementById("result4").value;
  var result1=parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y) + parseFloat(z) 
  + parseFloat(a); // conversion to numbers; this is necessary for +, other    operators will automatically convert 
  var result5=x%y;
  
  //build a string first and then display it all together.
  //don't forget HTML tags in your output!

  var html="<p>Your GPA is: "+result1/4+"</p>"; 
 


  
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=html;
 }
 
 
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<h1> <a href="http://kennesaw.edu "> <img src="images/ksu.jpg" alt="KSU
    Graphic"/> </a>CCSE Graduate Certificate in Health Information
    Technology<a href="http://kennesaw.edu "> <img src="images/ksu.jpg"
    alt="KSU Graphic"/> </a> 
</h1>

<nav> <a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a
    href="faculty.html"> Faculty</a> | <a href="third.html">
    Miscellaneous</a> 
</nav>

<p>The summer is coming and Cert HIT has some student assistant positions open. 
In order to be considered for such a position, a student has to complete the following 
4 classes and have an average grade of 3.5 or above: 
IT 3503 Foundation of HIT, IT 4153 Advanced Database, IT 5443 Web Development, & IT 5413 
Software Design and Development. Please enter the grades you have received in the four
classes.
</p>

<script language="JavaScript">

function calculateGpa (form) {
    var gpa = form.gpa1.value;

        if (gpa == "A") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "B") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "C") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "D") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "F") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
        if (gpa == "a") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "b") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "c") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "d") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "f") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = gpa;
}
</script>


<body>

<form action="" id="it3503">Enter your grade in the form of a letter grade for class IT 3503:<br>

<input type="text" name="gpa1" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateGpa(this.form)">
</form>
<div id="result1"></div>


<script language="JavaScript">

function calculateGpa2 (form) {
    var gpa = form.gpa2.value;

        if (gpa == "A") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "B") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "C") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "D") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "F") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
        if (gpa == "a") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "b") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "c") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "d") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "f") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = gpa;
}
</script>


<body>

<form action="" id="it4153">Enter your grade in the form of a letter grade for class IT 4153:<br>

<input type="text" name="gpa2" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateGpa2(this.form)">
</form>
<div id="result2"></div>


<script language="JavaScript">
function calculateGpa3 (form) {
    var gpa = form.gpa3.value;

        if (gpa == "A") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "B") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "C") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "D") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "F") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
        if (gpa == "a") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "b") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "c") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "d") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "f") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
    document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = gpa;
}
</script>


<body>

<form action="" id="it5443">Enter your grade in the form of a letter grade for class IT 5443:<br>

<input type="text" name="gpa3" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateGpa3(this.form)">
</form>
<div id="result3"></div>


<script language="JavaScript">
function calculateGpa4(form) {
    var gpa = form.gpa4.value;

        if (gpa == "A") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "B") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "C") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "D") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "F") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
        if (gpa == "a") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "b") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "c") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "d") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "f") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
    document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = gpa;


}
</script>


<body>

<form action="" id="it5413">Enter your grade in the form of a letter grade for class IT 5413:<br>

<input type="text" name="gpa4" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateGpa4(this.form)">
</form>
<div id="result4"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" id="final" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()">

<script type="text/javascript">
 function calculate()
 {
  var x=document.getElementById("result1").value;
  var y=document.getElementById("result2").value;
  var z=document.getElementById("result3").value;
  var a=document.getElementById("result4").value;
  var result1=parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y) + parseFloat(z) 
  + parseFloat(a); // conversion to numbers; this is necessary for +, other operators will automatically convert 
  var result5=x%y;
  
  //build a string first and then display it all together.
  //don't forget HTML tags in your output!

  var html="<p>Your GPA is: "+result1/4+"</p>"; 
 


  
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=html;
 }
 
 
 </script>





<div id="total"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You're putting the numeric grade into `.innerHTML`, but then `calculate()` tries to read it with `.value`. It needs to use `.innerHTML` to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your main problem is that you are trying to get the numberic data out of result1-result4 by using the value function.  However, a div element has no value function, you need to use innerText.

There are some other problems: you have defined calculate() twice, and there's no way to know which one will execute - I deleted the one at the end.

You've also got 4 open  tags, you should only have one open & close body tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>

<head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="styles.css"> <title>Center for Health Information Technology
</title> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function calculate()
 {
  var x=document.getElementById("result1").innerText;
  var y=document.getElementById("result2").innerText;
  var z=document.getElementById("result3").innerText;
  var a=document.getElementById("result4").innerText;
  var result1=parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y) + parseFloat(z) 
  + parseFloat(a); // conversion to numbers; this is necessary for +, other    operators will automatically convert 
  var result5=x%y;
  
  //build a string first and then display it all together.
  //don't forget HTML tags in your output!

  var html="<p>Your GPA is: "+result1/4+"</p>"; 
 


  
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=html;
 }
 
 
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<h1> <a href="http://kennesaw.edu "> <img src="images/ksu.jpg" alt="KSU
    Graphic"/> </a>CCSE Graduate Certificate in Health Information
    Technology<a href="http://kennesaw.edu "> <img src="images/ksu.jpg"
    alt="KSU Graphic"/> </a> 
</h1>

<nav> <a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a
    href="faculty.html"> Faculty</a> | <a href="third.html">
    Miscellaneous</a> 
</nav>

<p>The summer is coming and Cert HIT has some student assistant positions open. 
In order to be considered for such a position, a student has to complete the following 
4 classes and have an average grade of 3.5 or above: 
IT 3503 Foundation of HIT, IT 4153 Advanced Database, IT 5443 Web Development, & IT 5413 
Software Design and Development. Please enter the grades you have received in the four
classes.
</p>

<script language="JavaScript">

function calculateGpa (form) {
    var gpa = form.gpa1.value;

        if (gpa == "A") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "B") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "C") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "D") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "F") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
        if (gpa == "a") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "b") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "c") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "d") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "f") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = gpa;
}
</script>


<body>

<form action="" id="it3503">Enter your grade in the form of a letter grade for class IT 3503:<br>

<input type="text" name="gpa1" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateGpa(this.form)">
</form>
<div id="result1"></div>


<script language="JavaScript">

function calculateGpa2 (form) {
    var gpa = form.gpa2.value;

        if (gpa == "A") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "B") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "C") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "D") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "F") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
        if (gpa == "a") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "b") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "c") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "d") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "f") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = gpa;
}
</script>


<body>

<form action="" id="it4153">Enter your grade in the form of a letter grade for class IT 4153:<br>

<input type="text" name="gpa2" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateGpa2(this.form)">
</form>
<div id="result2"></div>


<script language="JavaScript">
function calculateGpa3 (form) {
    var gpa = form.gpa3.value;

        if (gpa == "A") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "B") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "C") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "D") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "F") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
        if (gpa == "a") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "b") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "c") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "d") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "f") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
    document.getElementById("result3").innerHTML = gpa;
}
</script>


<body>

<form action="" id="it5443">Enter your grade in the form of a letter grade for class IT 5443:<br>

<input type="text" name="gpa3" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateGpa3(this.form)">
</form>
<div id="result3"></div>


<script language="JavaScript">
function calculateGpa4(form) {
    var gpa = form.gpa4.value;

        if (gpa == "A") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "B") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "C") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "D") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "F") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
        if (gpa == "a") {
             gpa = 4;
             }
        if (gpa == "b") {
             gpa = 3;
             }
        if (gpa == "c") {
             gpa = 2;
             }
        if (gpa == "d") {
             gpa = 1;
         }
        if (gpa == "f") {
             gpa = 0;
         }
    document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = gpa;


}
</script>


<body>

<form action="" id="it5413">Enter your grade in the form of a letter grade for class IT 5413:<br>

<input type="text" name="gpa4" value="">
<input type="button" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculateGpa4(this.form)">
</form>
<div id="result4"></div>
<br>
<input type="button" id="final" name="button" value="Calculate" onClick="calculate()">






<div id="total"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br> <br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: *innerText* is a proprietary IE property, much better to use the W3C standard *textContent*.

Comment: I deleted the extra body tags and tried eliminating the .value in the calculate() function.  However, it still doesn't work.  I'm using the div elements to output the calculated gpa from the calculate function.  How can I get the numeric values output by the four calculateGpa functions and enter them into the calculate function?

Comment: @RobG I actually intended to use innerHTML but textContent is better than both

Comment: Stephen, there are several ways to improve your gpa calculator and make it less confusing.

Comment: @Stephen I recommend using only one calculate button, and changing the calculate() function to both scoop up the letter gpa values, convert them to  numeric values, and combine them into a gpa.  Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xnvqLgf5/

Comment: I've updated the code and it now outputs the gpa correctly. I'm having a perplexing problem though; after adding another function to determine eligibility based on gpa.  If I enter anything other than Fs I get the message that the user is eligible to apply for the scholarship.  If I enter all Ds or higher I get the output that the user is eligible to apply for the scholarship.  I learned from xrgb's post how to pass a value from a function into another function.  Using what I learned I took the value assigned to result1 and passed it into a determineEligibility, but the output is incorrect.

Comment: Stephen, the number you are passing to determineEligibility() is the sum of all the gpa numbers, you need to divide it by 4.